# How to delete entries in a dictionary with a given flag in python?

Tags: python, ruby, dictionary

I have a dictionary, lets call it `myDict`, in Python that contains a set of similar dictionaries which all have the entry "`turned_on : True`" or "`turned_on : False`". I want to remove all the entries in `myDict` that are off, e.g. where "`turned_on : False`". In Ruby I would do something like this:

```
myDict.delete_if { |id,dict| not dict[:turned_on] }
```

How should I do this in Python?

Comment: do you have a typo in `id2`? you don't have actually a key `turned_off`, do you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight-forward way:

```
def delete_if_not(predicate_key, some_dict):
    for key, subdict in some_dict.items():
        if not subdict.get(predicate_key, True):
            del some_dict[key]
```

Testing:

```
mydict = {
        'test1': {
                'turned_on': True,
                'other_data': 'foo',
            },
        'test2': {
            'turned_on': False,
            'other_data': 'bar',
            },
        }
delete_if_not('turned_on', mydict)
print mydict
```

The other answers on this page so far create another dict. They don't delete the keys in your actual dict.

Comment: it seems to be guarantee that all `subdicts` have a `'turned_on'` key.

Comment: adding the check costed me nothing and the function is now more generic (can be used in any dict of dicts).

Answer (score 7):

You mean like this?

```
myDict = {"id1" : {"turned_on": True}, "id2" : {"turned_on": False}}
result = dict((a, b) for a, b in myDict.items() if b["turned_on"])
```

output:

```
{'id1': {'turned_on': True}}
```

Comment: `turned_off` was just typo in the question.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you want, but my guess is:

```
myDict = {i: j for i, j in myDict.items() if j['turned_on']}
```

or for older version of python:

```
myDict = dict((i, j) for i, j in myDict.iteritems() if j['turned_on'])
```

Comment: Is this a Python3.0 thing? You can't do 'dict comprehensions' in 2.5, certainly.

Comment: Python 3.0 is a stable version of python. I've added py2k version for those downvoters who cannot expand this primitive syntax.

Comment: @SilentGhost: While I wouldn't downvote you, python 3 is not widely used yet, because of the lack of useful 3rd party libraries to do simple things, like connecting to some RDBMS, thus providing a py3-only answer is frowned upon for a while.

Comment: @nosklo: my dismay is aimed at those who cannot see past such a transparent syntax. py3k was out for almost 9 months out and is a stable version of python, providing only 2k version should be frowned upon too, don't you think. At this rate py3k will be adopted at the end of the century.

Comment: @SilentGhost: well, the python 2.x version works on python 3 just fine, so it is not frowned upon. Even if it did, it is still reasonable to assume everyone is using 2.x unless explicity noted, since 3.x is still hard to use for serious stuff.

Comment: http://python.org/ have lots of examples on that. If you click on DOCUMENTATION -> CURRENT DOCS (without specifying any version) it still redirects you to 2.6.2 docs. If you click on DOWNLOAD, there's a notice near the top of the page that says: *If you don't know which version to use, start with Python 2.6.2; more existing third party software is compatible with Python 2 than Python 3 right now.*

Comment: as well as: The **current production** versions are Python 2.6.2 and Python 3.1.1.

Start with one of these versions for learning Python or if you want the most stability; they're **both considered stable production releases**.

Emphasis mine

Comment: yeah, you just made my point. Python 2.x is listed first. And just after that sentence comes the one I said on my previous comment. python.org clearly favors 2.x, that's plain clear for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = { 'id1':{'turned_on':True}, 'id2':{'turned_on':False}}
dict((i,j) for i, j in d.items() if not j['turned_on'])
```